# How to .off() jquery click function?

Tags: jquery

How do I .off() the following function?

```
$(".primaryNav ul li a").click(function() {
    $(".primaryNav").slideUp(300);
});
```

Comment: are you referring to `.unblind()` like `$(".primaryNav ul li a").unbind( "click" );` ?

Comment: when you want to off() then event ?

Comment: `$(".primaryNav ul li a").off('click')`

Comment: `$(".primaryNav ul li a").off('click');` **but** that would unbind all click event bound using jQuery to this matched set, not only this specific function. In later case, you need to use referenced method as event handler or namespaced event

Comment: @A.Wolff Could you give me an example of how I would go about making sure only this particular function was turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unbind only specific handler:

1. Using namespaced event

   $(".primaryNav ul li a").on("click.slideUp", function() {
       $(".primaryNav").slideUp(300);
   });

   $(".primaryNav ul li a").off("click.slideUp");
2. Using referenced handler

   function clickSlideUp(){
     $(".primaryNav").slideUp(300);
   }

   $(".primaryNav ul li a").on("click", clickSlideUp);

   $(".primaryNav ul li a").off("click", clickSlideUp);

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Your comment and answer have been upvoted, you've provided a really clear and well organised answer :]